# Block drivers have major and minor numbers?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-driver

can anyone please tell me block driver have major and minor number? if block  driver doesn't have major and minor number then how it identifies the different set of connected devices in computer?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you have, the reason why you ask this question? And if you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "block driver", but *block **device*** definitely has both major and minor numbers.